# sample /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf file to run rails app on nginx successfully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, nginx

What should be the sample nginx.conf file to run a rails app using nginx server. nginx was installed with `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module` and through `apt-get install nginx` don't know which nginx setting to be used?. How to configure nginx.conf file to get rid of `index.html` not found error while `passenger_enabled on;` is still there in `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` file. the file also uses correct ruby and passenger. I am fed up of nginx installation issue.

Comment: have you looked at this? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

See this example:

https://gist.github.com/mikhailov/711913

[And now here's some extraneous text because SO is needlessly requiring me to enter 30 characters in this field, instead of 18.]